# Excel add-in to show all the controls

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm making an add-in that will show a message box for each control that I have in the Excel document.
But when I open it with some Excel document (that has many controls like buttons/check-boxes) by adding it as a COM Add-in, nothing happens, and when I open the *COM Add-ins* again, I see that my add-in is unchecked :(

What can be the problem?

This is the code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Tools.Worksheet vstoWork = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[0]);
    foreach (Control c in vstoWork.Controls)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
    }
}
```

My end goal is to identify all the controls that are buttons and click them, but this is for now.

Thanks.